# How to iterate array list in Thymeleaf template?

Tags: iteration, thymeleaf

I am trying to write out items from array list and make a checkboxes from them. What is wrong with this template?

Template **grant_access.html**

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/accounts/grant_access}" th:object="${request}" method="post">
        <div th:each="scope:${request.requestScopes}" class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="${scope.id}" />&nbsp;${scope.scope}

            </label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" name="action" value="authorize" class="btn btn-default">Authorize</button>
        <button type="submit" name="action" value="cancel" class="btn btn-link">Cancel</button>
    </form>
```

This is the **output**, codes are not translated into values.

```
<form action="/restapi/accounts/grant_access" method="post">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="${scope.id}" />&nbsp;${scope.scope}
        </label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="action" value="authorize" class="btn btn-default">Authorize</button>
    <button type="submit" name="action" value="cancel" class="btn btn-link">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

This is a **controller** and request object:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/grant_access", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView authorize(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {

List<Scope> scopes = scopeService.getRequestedScopes(authorizationRequest.getScope());

        GrantRequest request = new GrantRequest();
        request.setAccount(account);
        request.setClient(client);
        request.setRequestScopes(scopes);

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("grant_access");
        modelAndView.addObject("request", request);

        return modelAndView;
}
```

and GrantRequest class:

```
public class GrantRequest {

    private Account account;
    private Client client;
    private ArrayList<Long> scopeIds;
    private List<Scope> requestScopes;
// getters and setters omitted...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `th:` prefix so that Thymeleaf actually processes the attributes:

```
<input type="checkbox" th:value="${scope.id}" />&nbsp;<span th:text="${scope.scope}" />
```

Note that `value` is now `th:value`, and the `${scope.scope}` part is now contained in a span, so that it's value can be processed.